# Como utilzar o comando while para mostrar o menor valor digitado pelo usuário?

Tags: javascript

Gente estou com dificuldades em resolver o seguinte problema:

Crie um algoritmo que receba vários números e encerre a leitura quando o usuário digitar o zero, ao final ele deve mostrar o menor dos números digitados.

```
var numero, menor = 1 
numero = prompt("Digite um numero: ")

while(numero != 0){ 
   if(menor < numero){
      menor = numero
   }

   document.write("Menor valor digitado é:  ", menor)     
}
```

Comment: Onde está o código?

Comment: Dsclp sou nova por aqui, editei a minha pergunta para que possa ver o código

Answer (score 2):

Pode fazer desta forma:

```js
var numero, menor;
while(numero != 0){
   numero = +prompt("Digite um numero: ");
   if(numero == 0){
      document.write("Menor valor digitado é:  ", menor ? menor : "nenhum número foi digitado");
      break;
   }

   if(!menor || numero < menor){
      menor = numero;
   }
}
```

Explicando:

O prompt retorna uma string. Adicionando o sinal de `+` antes irá converter o número digitado em tipo `Number`:

```
+prompt("Digite um numero: ")
```

É preciso fazer essa conversão porque senão você irá comparar strings, e "10" é menor que "5", por exemplo.

E o prompt deve estar dentro do `while` senão irá gerar um loop infinito, pois caso seja digitado um número diferente de `0`, o `while` irá rodar pra sempre, e o prompt não será chamado novamente.

Outra coisa, é declarar a variável `menor` sem valor, pois se for `1`, nenhum número digitado no prompt será menor (não estou considerando a possibilidade de digitar número negativos no seu código original).

O segundo `if` verifica se o valor de `menor` é indefinido ou menor que o número digitado. Qualquer uma dessas condições irá reatribuir à variável o valor digitado.

Caso o usuário digite `0`, irá mostrar a mensagem e parar o `while` com `break`, já que não importa mais ele continuar.

Comment: Muito obrigada pela ajuda!!!!!!!!!!